# Create angularJS scope property object keys dynamically based on data entered by users

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does anyone know how, using angularjs, to create scope property objects and keys dynamically?

Basically I'm making a single page web app that, amongst other things, allows a user to paste into a textarea tab-delineated data from Excel (or wherever else) containing the names of students, and the number of marks they got on each question on an assessment.

Now, obviously, every assessment doesn't have exactly the same number of questions, nor is every question the same mark on each assessment.

Therefore I am trying to set it up so that they can input the data for just the headings first, creating keys in a scope property object that can then have values filled in when the user inputs their assessment data including the students names.

If you're interested in seeing what I've got so far it's on my github here - https://github.com/jcreek/AssessmentAnalyser

I have got the data coming in to a table in the DOM but I need to populate the objects in the scope property with the same keys, rather than putting it into a table.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your textarea data?

Comment: It's literally just: 

StudentName, Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.

Comment: What about the mark for each Q?

Comment: The marks are integers, although each question will have a different maximum mark.

Comment: Use [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).